# TYPO3 Hook not found

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

I am currently trying to write a Hook to add extra fields to a Flexform. Therefore I followed this tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ExtendFlexforms/Index.html?fref=gc&dti=250938618364487#extend-flexforms-with-custom-fields

But when I go to a page in the backend that contains an options from a Flexform I get the following Error:
Class 'ID\SearchBarAdditional\Hooks\FlexFormHook' not found.

I register the Hook in the ext_localconf like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS'][\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\FlexForm\FlexFormTools::class]['flexParsing'][] = \ID\SearchBarAdditional\Hooks\FlexFormHook::class;
```

and my Hook-file is here: typo3conf/ext/search_bar_additional/Classes/Hooks
and is initialized that way:

```
namespace ID\SearchBarAdditional\Hooks;
class FlexFormHook { /* ... */
```

So in my opinion everything is in the right place and should work, but I do still get the error that TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance("ID\SearchBarAdditional\Hooks\FlexFormHook") fails.

Do you guys have any ideas, what could be wrong? Do I have to register the Hook in \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin( or something similar (as the posted code is really the only thing I've done)?

Comment: Whenever you add new PHP classes to your extension, they need to be registered/autoloaded. Easiest way is, to deinstall/install your extensions via ExtensionManager, or using installtool 'Dump Autoload Information' in TYPO3 CMS 8

Comment: sadly this did not work :(

Comment: Reinstalling or dumping class loading is not enough if the class loading is not registered correctly to begin with, which appears to be the problem in this case.

Comment: @user1508609 are you using composer? Do you have a file typo3conf/ext/search_bar_additional/composer.json?

Comment: no, I am not using composer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical class loading error. Check that you added your PHP namespaces to composer autoloading and/or `ext_emconf.php` and make sure your filenames are correctly named according to PSR-4. If in doubt you can inspect the class loading map files generated by composer in vendor/composer (if you use composer for class loading, which you definitely should do).

Comment: I am not using composer, so I guess it's the other one.
But the 'Classes'-Folder gets loaded in the ext_emconf.php, so the Hook-Folder should be loaded too:
`'autoload' => [
        'psr-4' => [
            'ID\\IndexedSearchAutocomplete\\' => 'Classes'
        ],
    ],`

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake: My Hook does indeed not get loaded. I tried to 'include' it in the ext_localconf.php and it is working now.
But as this is of course an extremely ugly solution I posted a second question, how to load a hook here: [Typo3 8.X - autoload Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024345/typo3-8-x-autoload-hook)

Thank you for your help!!!