# TYPO3 8.X - autoload Hook

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

How can I autoload a hook in TYPO3?

I register it in the `ext_localconf.php`, but it does not get autoloaded (unless I 'include' it in the same file which is of course an extremely ugly solution).
I looked into other extensions but I don't find, where the require there hooks.
Shouldn't it be autoloaded in the ext_emconf?

```
'autoload' => [
    'psr-4' => [
        'ID\\IndexedSearchAutocomplete\\' => 'Classes'
    ],
],
```

But when don't use my ugly solution I get the error, that GeneralUtility::makeInstance can't find my file.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? http://insight.helhum.io/post/130876393595/how-to-configure-class-loading-for-extensions-in

This article describes the options you have regarding class loading.

You may want to check whether your class fulfills the psr-4 standard: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using composer in your project. Composer does the whole autoloading of classes. It "knows" all classes of extensions that were required by composer (listed in the `require` part of your `composer.json`).

Of course you can add extensions to your project without requiering them with composer. I guess, that is what you did here. In that case you have to tell composer about the classes in your `composer.json`.

Add a `autoload` section:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "ID\\IndexedSearchAutocomplete\\": "web/typo3conf/ext/indexed_search_autocomplete/Classes"
    }
}
```

Of course your FQCN have to match the path above your Classes folder (that is what psr-4 means).

After that you can type `composer dump-autoload` and your class should be loaded.

Comment: No, I am not using composer - but thank you very much for your answer.